# How can we fetch and display images from our local drive using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image, web-applications, dom-events

How can we fetch and display **images** from our local drive using **Javascript**?

Sample Image path is:

> file:///E://DCRMS_ATTACHED_FILES/sensor_images/Sunset.jpg

**JS code:**

```
var h = "<table border='0' cellpadding='1' cellspacing='4' style='font-size:.8em;'>",p=feature.attributes;
if(feature.attributes.image_name)
{   
       alert(feature.attributes.image_name);//here i'm getting complete path to display img 
    h +="<tr><th style='font-weight:bold;'><img src="+feature.attributes.image_name+" width='100%' height='100%'></img><td></td></th></tr>";
    h   +="</table>";           
}
```

Comment: Is your url also `file://...`? Else, it is disallowed by the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

Comment: Dear DarkCthulhu, Thanks for your reply.. my images is at "E://DCRMS_ATTACHED_FILES/sensor_images/Sunset.jpg" path. But, I can show that only when i tried to add like below format in browser "file:///E://DCRMS_ATTACHED_FILES/sensor_images/Sunset.jpg"

Comment: This is probably not a good idea since the path would be visible in the code. Can you do it by a server-side language such as php and then just unhide when you need it?

Comment: Dear fditz, thank you for your reply, actually from database i'm getting only the image "name.format" and then i will concatenate that with my properties file ("local drive") path. So, if i can do that in js that will be helpful..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only possible answer: No, you can't.
For security reasons, your local files can't be accessed by the browser.
Or would you like to know that some website is accessing your hard drive?